# mysql cannot update one row to multi data when no duplicates exists

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update my table with respect to anothe table by query

```
UPDATE(
    tmp_a as a
    inner join 
    tmp_b as b
    on a.id=b.id)
set a.name=b.name,
    a.code=b.code;
```

this return **cannot update one row to multi-data** error.

then I tried the following query

```
create temporary table tmp_c(
    select a.id as id_a,a.name as name_a,a.code as code_a,
        b.id as id_b,b.name as name_b,b.code as code_b
    from(
    tmp_a as a
    inner join 
    tmp_b as b
    on a.id=b.id
    )
);

UPDATE tmp_c
set name_a=name_b
    code_a=code_b
;
```

there is not error message return, which means, from my understanding, there is actually no one row to multi-data relationship problem exists in my datasets.

Then why does the **cannot update one row to multi-data** error occur here and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that MySQL supports your update syntax.  Just use a standard update join instead:

```sql
UPDATE tmp_a a
INNER JOIN tmp_b b
    ON a.id = b.id
SET a.name = b.name,
    a.code = b.code;
```

Comment: Apologize that I lost my comma in SET statement by accident, but other than that, from my perspective your query is exactly the same as first query of my post except brackets around INNER JOIN.

Comment: Not the same at all...you are trying to update an inline intermediate table.  I have never seen or used this syntax on MySQL, but perhaps 8+ does support this.

Comment: I cannot see any difference between your query and first query of my post except brackets and indent, but as I know indent does not matter in mysql, do you mean brackets may have special meaning other than changing priority in sql?

Comment: @Yuhan *I cannot see any difference between your query and first query of my post except **brackets** and indent,* "Beauty is evil"... these brackets converts two separate source tables to solid and non-updatable dynamic rowset.